# Very slow printing with Dymo Label-Printer on Raspbian and CUPS

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, cups, printer

I have a problem with label printing on a Raspberry Pi:

When I start a print on a Dymo LabelWriter 450 Turbo with CUPS and drivers from [matthiasbock/dymo-cups-drivers](https://github.com/matthiasbock/dymo-cups-drivers) it takes about 6-7 seconds until the print starts. The printing itself is then very slow. At the end of printing, the printer pauses for about 1-2 seconds and then advances the last piece of the label.

System is a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspian - but I have the exact same problem on a current Ubuntu on my workstation.

The quirks file from [8-10 Sec delay between jobs DYMO 450 Turbo USB](https://github.com/apple/cups/issues/5521) is integrated and doesn't help. Setting usb no-reattach doesn't help either.

Does anyone know about this problem or have an idea where I could tackle this problem?

I would be happy about every idea and every suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

For me worked using the standard dymo driver which comes with cups "DYMO Label Printer". Under Ubuntu you can thoose it from Search Database -> Dymo -> Dymo Label Printer. Hopes that helps and you can adapt on Rasperry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

I have no solution, but it works in my setup. I hope sharing this information with you might help you to debug or solve your issue.

I've just configured my Raspberry Pi Model B running a headless Raspbian 10 as a CUPS server. One of my printers is a LaberWriter 450. I've installed the drivers from this [repo](https://github.com/Kyle-Falconer/DYMO-SDK-for-Linux) and it work right away.

The raspberry and the Dymo requires about 3 seconds to start printing, and the print speed is the same as for USB connection.